# Countif show in msgbox?

Tags: excel, vba

I want a sub to Count if the value of a cell is equal to either 1,2,3,4 or 5. Then it should show that Numbers of `1 = "xxx"`, Numbers of `2="xxx"` and so on.

```
Sub Opgave3()
    Dim n As Long
    n = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns("I"), "1")
    If n = 1 Then _
    MsgBox "All in Fakultet:" & n & "123", vbInformation, "Heres the answer"
End Sub
```

This isnt showing any msgbox with the value of Column i equal to 1 - Why?

Comment: i dont quite understand what you want to achieve, can you provide a theoretical example with some fictional data?

Answer (score 2):

If it's not showing the `MsgBox`, it's probably because `n` is not equal to `1`.

This would probably be because Column `I` has either *zero*, or *2 or more*, cells whose entire value is `1`.

**Your code says:**

> If `1` is the value of exactly 1 cell in column `I`, then display a message box that says:
>
> *"`All in Fakultet:1123`"* with a title of *"`Heres the answer`"*

Answer (score 0):

Hi This code should be like this, you can only call the Columns and Rows by index number not by Alpha

```
   Sub Opgave3()
   Dim n As Long
   n = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(9), "1")
   If n = 1 Then _
   MsgBox "All in Fakultet:" & n & "123", vbInformation, "Heres the answer"
   End Sub
```